# How to escape regular expression characters from variable in JMeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

Problem is simple. I have regular expression used to extract some data from response. It looks like that:

```
<input type="hidden" +name="reportpreset_id" +value="(\w+)" *>${reportPresetName}</td>
```

Problem is that variable `${reportPresetName}` may contain characters used by regular expression like parenthesis or dots.
I've tried to surround this variable with `\Q` and `\E` (based on [that](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)) but apparently these markers don't work (apparently Java supports this markers so I'm confused).
When I'm adding that markers even then this expression fails for any content of  `${reportPresetName}` variable (even for cases when it was working without those markers).

I've checked [list of functions in JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), but I didn't found anything useful.
Does anyone know how to escape regular expression characters in JMeter?

---

update:
When I'm using this `\Q` and `\E` with assertion it fails. When I'm doing a copy of regular expression from assertion log in "View Results Tree" and testing it on recorded response data it works! So it looks like some kind bug in JMeter.

Comment: I've reported a bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54176

Comment: It is a bug since `\Q` and `\E` works inside "View Results Tree", this proofs that there are two engines of RE in JMeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jmeter uses jakarta ORO as its regexp engine in Regexp Extractor and Regexp Tester:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

But it uses Java Regexp Engine for search in HTML/Text Viewer.

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html $20.4

  ```
  Please note that ORO does not support the \Q and \E meta-characters. 
  [In other RE engines, these can be used to quote a portion of an RE so that the 
  meta-characters stand for themselves.]
  ```

A solution for you would be to add a JSR223 post processor using Groovy after regexp that extracts the var and escapes regexp chars using:

```
org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Compiler.quotemeta(String valueToEscape)
```

As of upcoming version 2.9, a new function has been created to do so:

- __escapeOroRegexpChars(String to escape, Variable Name)

Comment: Ok, `\Q` and `\E` won't work, but how do I escape this spatial characters in assertion and post processors of JMeters?

Comment: JSR223 and Groovy looks promising, I have to try it.

Comment: I will use `BSF Sampler` to create new or replace variable, since I will use this value multiple times. THX.

Answer (score 1):

`\Q` and `\E` work in Java, see [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

In Java, we use to double the backslash characters, though, so you might need to use `(\\w+)` and, of course, `\\Q` and `\\E`.

I am not sure in your case, as I don't understand your context, actually (never used JMeter so far).

Comment: Ok. Java does use `\Q` and `\E`, but it doesn't work for me in JMeter (pure Java app) that is why I assume that its Java fault.

Comment: Have you tried to double the backslash characters in your expression?

Comment: there no no point to do it. JMeter is more like end user app, you do not compile test cases, you just build a tree of some objects, so you don't have to do extra escaping like double slash. In my case `\w` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case JMeter does not support `\\Q` and `\\E` (which I don't know if does...), you can write your own function/procedure, where you will split string into characters and replace each character with escaped sequence as follows:

- if the character is `\`, then replace it with `\\\\`
- otherwise add before the character a prefix `\\`

This is not the optimal method, but for sure it will work as needed.

---

For example for input

```
This is-a\string 12&$34|!`^5
```

you will get

```
\\T\\h\\i\\s\\ \\i\\s\\-\\a\\\\s\\t\\r\\i\\n\\g\\ \\1\\2\\&\\$\\3\\4\\|\\!\\`\\^\\5
```